# django-model-utils: does InheritanceManager work if the parent model/class is abstract?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

[django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils).
I'm attempting the very basic use of InhertianceManager as described in the docs.

```
nearby_places = Place.objects.filter(location='here').select_subclasses()
```

**The only difference is that my parent model/class is abstract. Is this still supposed to work?**

I am getting errors like

> Caught DatabaseError while rendering: (1146, "Table 'proj.ParentModel'
>   doesn't exist")

and

> 'Options' object has no attribute '_join_cache'

both of which are errors one typically gets when you attempt to do a query on an abstract class.

in my parent model i've defined the manager as follows:

```
class ParentModel(OrderedModel):
    objects = InheritanceManager()
```

Answer (score 5):

following the link from the docs to [Jeff Elmore's blog](http://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/) (aka the author of the InheritanceManager) he describes how InheritanceManager works.

It is quite clear that the parent model/class cannot be abstract.

.... actually i should have figured this out from the code the first time around.....