# Query only specific subclass(es) of an abstract superclass

Tags: django, django-models

This question is fundamentally similar to these previous questions:

- [Django access to subclasses items from abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742870/django-access-to-subclasses-items-from-abstract-class)
- [How to query abstract-class-based objects in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797982/how-to-query-abstract-class-based-objects-in-django)

I am posting this as a new, separate question because:

- I have minor additional considerations that aren't addressed in the previous questions
- The previous questions are relatively old, and if it's the case that the correct answer has changed in recent times, I wonder if maybe those questions haven't been visible enough  (given that they have accepted answers) to get the attention of those who might know about such potential changes.

With that in mind, I'll take the question from the top and define it fully and concretely - and I leave it to the hive to determine if a close-duplicate is in order.

**Background**

Say I am constructing models to represent parts of a building. I split the building into logical classes:

- `Floor`
- `BuildingSpace(ABC)`
- `Office(BuildingSpace)`
- `CommonArea(BuildingSpace)`

**Goal**

Under `Floor`, I want methods that can retrieve all buildingspaces - *or*, either of its two subclasses separately:

```py
from typing import Type
class Floor(models.Model):
    def getAllSpaces():
        # return all objects that satisfy Type[BuildingSpace]
    def getAllOffices():
        # return all objects that satisfy strictly and only Type[Office]
    def getAllCommonAreas():
        # return all objects that satisfy strictly and only Type[CommonArea]
```

**Possible solutions**

`django-model-utils` looks like it can support this kind of a query out-of-the-box with its [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) and the `.select_subclass()` method -- but, crucially, [requires `BuildingSpace` to be concrete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10006838/4604845), so that leaves this solution with having to go with multi-table inheritance. Which I understand amplifies database load for each query, so I looked into making the subclasses proxies in order to mitigate that, but [InheritanceManager doesn't support proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291002/using-inheritancemanager-django-model-utils-on-proxy-models). When all is said and done, `django-model-utils` look to me like it unavoidably opens me to multi-table inheritance penalties at query time.

`django-polymorphic` also supports this out-of-the-box as far as I have been able to glean, using `.instance_of(subclass)`. Purely from a coding point-of-view, this approach looks very clean and easy to use. But it also looks to [come with database performance considerations](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/performance.html), and making it [admin-panel compliant](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/admin.html) looks non-trivial at a first, superficial glance.

Natively, it looks `django` can do this in some roundabout way, but I've seen claims that achieving the same functionality as described above with a native `QuerySet.filter()` approach is worse performance-wise than both of the above extensions.

A final alternative solution I've briefly considered, that I assume will work natively without creating database considerations (but does require a slight redesign) - is to access the subclass managers directly, and then have the desired outcome of `getAllSpaces()` implemented via a `QuerySet.Union`-type of approach.

**Almost-MRE**

Naïve setup of how I had imagined to be able to use the code:

```py
class BuildingSpace(models.Model):
    floor  = models.ForeignKey('Floor', 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                related_name="interiors")
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Floor(models.Model):
    def _InteriorManager(self): # get the default manager of BuildingSpace
        return self.interiors
    def GetAllInteriors(self):
        return self._InteriorManager().all() # get the full Type[BuildingSpace] queryset, but this isn't supported in native django

    def GetOffices(self):
        return self._InteriorManager().instance_of(Office) # django-polymorphic
    def GetCommonAreas(self):
        return self._InteriorManager().select_subclasses(CommonAreas).all() # django-model-utils
```

**Question**

I'm hoping to get answers that can weigh in on the following factors:

- is there any significant difference in performance between `django-model-utils`, `django-polymorphic` and some other best-case `QuerySet.filter()`-based approach for the cases described here (and potentially, the linked questions at the top)
- does either extension implicate any other consideration that is worth noting (ease of use, extensibility, how additional filtering is done, etc)
- would my "final alternative solution" in the end maybe work better on all accounts (performance, ease of use, extensibility) if it is the case that the use-cases I need solved are never more complex than the concrete code examples I've provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no insights as to the database performance topic as of yet, but I will say this:

`django-polymorphic` is really smooth to use. Minimal code adaptation required, and the syntax is both short and intuitive. The perceived difficulty of making it compliant with the admin-panel was a smokescreen, at least as long as you do basic, straightforward subclassing.

For anyone coming this way with similar troubles, don't hesitate to try it. You can't use it on abstract classes, as mentioned, but unless you have really particular needs it does look like having a concrete superclass and just using this library is a whole lot easier than jerry-rigging a manual solution similar to the one I described in the question.